# How can I set a text color for a selected CollectionView item?

Tags: xaml, maui

Here is my CollectionView:

```
            <CollectionView 
                    Margin="5,5,5,15"
                    ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguage, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding LanguageChangedCommand}"
                    SelectionMode="Single">
                <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" />
                </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="language:CultureInfo">
                        <ContentView Padding="5" >
                            <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,3*">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Image Source="{Binding TwoLetterISOLanguageName, StringFormat='flag_{0}.png'}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding DisplayName}" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ContentView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

And here is my style:

```
<Style TargetType="ContentView">
    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource LaticreteColor}" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here I set background color of the selected item. But I also need to set text color of the selected item, and TextColor property does not exist:

"Cannot resolve property "TextColor" on type "ContentView (property missing or missing accessors)"."

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the effect, you can use `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` to make it work. Please try adding `x:Name` for the [Label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.label?view=net-maui-7.0) and then use  to set the `TextColor` for the [Label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.label?view=net-maui-7.0). See [Set state on multiple elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/visual-states#set-state-on-multiple-elements).

Please refer to the sample code below:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
       <Style TargetType="ContentView">
            <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                <VisualStateGroupList>
                    <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">

                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>

                        <VisualState Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Yellow" />
                                <Setter TargetName="label" Property="Label.TextColor" Value="Red" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateGroupList>
               
            </Setter>          
        </Style>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Monkeys}"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        SelectionChanged="OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentView Padding="5">
                        <Grid Padding="10">  
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"
                               Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                               Aspect="AspectFill"
                               HeightRequest="60"
                               WidthRequest="60" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1"
                               Text="{Binding Name}"
                               FontAttributes="Bold" />
                        <Label Grid.Row="1"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               
                               x:Name="label"
                               Text="{Binding Location}"
                               FontAttributes="Italic"
                               VerticalOptions="End" />
                    </Grid>
                    </ContentView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The solution would be to put a `VisualStateGroup` directly on your `DataTemplate` in the areas you need it, so, you can put one directly on the `ContentView` for the `BackgroundColor` but, you can also put one directly on the `Label` for `TextColor`.

However, I found a quirk/bug with `CollectionView` not showing the VisualGroup correctly on startup. Only after you've interacted with the `CollectionView` do you see the outcome, hence, any initial value in the `SelectedLanguages` will not be shown to the user.

There are two workarounds needed to resolve that issue:

1. Add a delay, approx. 500ms, on app startup to delay set the `SelectedLanguages`
2. Replace `VisualStateGroup` with a `Binding` (or `MultiBinding`).

Here, I've used a simplistic `CompareToObjectConverter`. You'll see that this has been hardcoded to only recognize strings, but, you can generalize for other types:

```cs
public class CompareToObjectConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length != 4)
            throw new ArgumentException("Must have four values");
        return values[0]?.ToString() == values[1]?.ToString() ? values[2] : values[3];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then, in your XAML, you can refer to this converter in your `Bindings`:

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml ... -->
<ContentPage>
    <!-- ... -->
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:CompareToObjectConverter x:Key="CompareToObjectConverter"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <!-- ... -->
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLanguage, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ContentView>
                    <ContentView.BackgroundColor>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{x:StaticResource CompareToObjectConverter}">
                            <Binding Path="SelectedLanguage.Name" Source="{x:RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainPage}}"/>
                            <Binding Path="Name"/>
                            <Binding Path="." Source="{x:Static Colors.LightSteelBlue}"/>
                            <Binding Path="." Source="{x:Static Colors.Transparent}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </ContentView.BackgroundColor>
                    <Grid ColumnDefinitions="*,*">
                        <Image Source="{Binding TwoLetterISOLanguageName, StringFormat='flag_{0}.png'}"/>
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DisplayName}">
                            <Label.TextColor>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{x:StaticResource CompareToObjectConverter}">
                                    <Binding Path="SelectedLanguage.Name" Source="{x:RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:MainPage}}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="Name"/>
                                    <Binding Path="." Source="{x:Static Colors.White}"/>
                                    <Binding Path="." Source="{x:Static Colors.Black}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Label.TextColor>
                        </Label>
                    </Grid>
                </ContentView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Surprisingly, solution offered by 
Alexandar May - MSFT does work without problems. Maybe the bug has already been fixed?